# Comparing two differently formatted lists in Python?

Tags: python

I need to compare two lists of records.  One list has records that are stored in a network drive:

C:\root\to\file.pdf

O:\another\root\to\record.pdf

...

The other list has records stored in ProjectWise, collaboration software.  It contains only filenames:

drawing.pdf

file.pdf

...

I want to create a list of the network drive file paths that do not have a filename that is in the ProjectWise list. It must include the paths.  Currently, I am searching a list of each line in the drive list with a regular expression consisting of a line ending with any of the names in the ProjectWise list.  The script is taking an unbearably long time and I feel I am overcomplicating the process.

I have thought about using sets to compare the lists (set(list1)-set(list2)) but this would only work with and return filenames on their own without the paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `os.path.basename` on the list that contains full paths to the file you can get the filename and can then compare that to the other list.

```
import os

orig_list = [path_dict[os.path.basename(path) for path in file_path_list]

missing_filepaths = set(orig_list) - set(file_name_list)
```

that will get you a list of all filenames that don't have an associated path and you should be able to go from there.

Edit:
So, you want a list of paths that don't have an associated filename, correct? Then pretty simple. Extending from the code before you can do this:

```
paths_without_filenames = [path for path in file_path_list if os.path.split(path)[1] in missing_filepaths]
```

this will generate a list of filepaths from your list of filepaths that don't have an associated filename in the list of filenames.

Comment: That much isn't the problem, but how do I go from that list to to adding back the associated paths?

Comment: @IanNormile edited answer to hopefully help. Looking up the `os.path` library will probably do you good for your future endeavors. Good luck!